# WSO2 API Manager download API Definition

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there a way to download API definition (JSON or YML) from Developer Portal? I mean, is there any default link I can point to get this file from API or API Product?

PS: It is easy to do it from Publisher interface but I can't find any option on DP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the API definition from the Devportal as well. Click on the Swagger as in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Great! It is pretty hidden! =D